# how to print limited number values in java script?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, printing, operators

I am a student and a beginner to the programming world. I need to take 1 to 10 and print less than 5 values. I have the following Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        for (let i = 1; i<10; i++){
            document.write('The Number is'+ i +'<br>');
        }
    </script>
```

but it is printing values between 1-9. I only need values 1-5. What should I try?

Comment: run the loop till 5 instead of 10

Comment: Change loop to `for (let i = 1; i<5; i++){`

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal it should be for (let i = 1; i<6; i++){

Comment: But the question says it has to take 1 to 10, but print 1 to 5.

Comment: @Yousername is correct I need take 1 to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a conditional in the loop where you are taking the input. The input can be from 1 - 10 (as mentioned in the question) but for each input you need to check your condition (less than 5) and perform an action only when the condition is true

```js
for (let i = 1; i<10; i++){    
    if( i < 5) {
        document.write('The Number is'+ i +'<br>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        for (let i = 1; i<10; i++){
            document.write('The Number is'+ i +'<br>');
            if(i = 5){
                   break;
            }
        }
</script>
```

try this